# Thinking of a way to add a counter corresponding to each hash address of the table?

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, linked-list, hashmap

I am creating a hashtable using linked list, I have the table working fine, but I need to create a counter for each address in the table.

The program must keep track of the current collision count for each address in the table. To do this, there must be a counter for each address. The addresses are 0 .. tableSize-1. Each time the program inserts an element, it must increment the counter corresponding to the hash address of the element. Similarly, whenever an element is deleted from the table, the counter corresponding to the hash address of the element must be decremented.

Should I add a variable to my list or hashtable to keep track.I dont want to include too much code to make things confusing so I will include snippets from my linkedList.cpp and Hashtable.cpp.

Hashtable.cpp

```
#include "HashTable.h"

// Constructs the empty Hash Table object.
// Array length is set to 13 by default.
HashTable::HashTable( int tableLength )
{
if (tableLength <= 0) tableLength = 13;
array = new LinkedList[ tableLength ];
length = tableLength;
}

// Returns an array location for a given item key.
int HashTable::hash( string itemKey )
{
int hashAddress=0;


for ( int i = 0; i < itemKey.length(); i++ )
   hashAddress= atoi(itemKey.c_str());
return (hashAddress  ) % length;
}

// Adds an item to the Hash Table.
void HashTable::insertItem( Item * newItem )
{
int index = hash( newItem -> key );
array[ index ].insertItem( newItem );
}

// Deletes an Item by key from the Hash Table.
// Returns true if the operation is successful.
bool HashTable::removeItem( string itemKey )
{
int index = hash( itemKey );
return array[ index ].removeItem( itemKey );
}

// Returns an item from the Hash Table by key.
// If the item isn't found, a null pointer is returned.
Item * HashTable::getItemByKey( string itemKey )
{
```

. . .

Linklist.cpp

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

// Constructs the empty linked list object.
// Creates the head node and sets length to zero.
LinkedList::LinkedList()
  {
   head = new Item;
   head -> next = NULL;
   length = 0;
}

// Inserts an item at the end of the list.
void LinkedList::insertItem( Item * newItem )
{
if (!head -> next)
{
    head -> next = newItem;
    length++;
    return;
}
Item * p = head;
Item * q = head;
while (q)
{
    p = q;
    q = p -> next;
}
p -> next = newItem;
newItem -> next = NULL;
length++;
}

// Removes an item from the list by item key.
// Returns true if the operation is successful.
bool LinkedList::removeItem( string itemKey )
{
if (!head -> next) return false;
Item * p = head;
Item * q = head;
while (q)
{
    if (q -> key == itemKey)
    {
        p -> next = q -> next;
        delete q;
        length--;
        return true;
    }
    p = q;
    q = p -> next;
}
return false;
}

// Searches for an item by its key.
// Returns a reference to first match.
// Returns a NULL pointer if no match is found.
Item * LinkedList::getItem( string itemKey )
```

. . .

Comment: Could this be a question for Programmers.SE? Finally???

Comment: _"I dont want to include too much code to make things confusing so I will include snippets"_ No mate don't include "snippets". Post a _complete_ but _minimal_ example that represents what you're talking about. That will effectively be "your code" within the scope of this question. You can take what you learn and apply it to your real, longer code afterwards.

Comment: You already have such a counter! It's `LinkedList::length`.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, **you're already maintaining such a counter**. All you have to do is make a new method that gets you that variable. You can implement something on these lines in the file where you implement your 'LinkedList' methods.

```cpp
int LinkedList::getCounter(int address)
{
   if(address>length)//referring to length of HashTable class
      return -1;
   return array[address].length;
}
```